# ONNX inference not working for multi-speaker

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, text-to-speech, onnx

I tried converting multi speaker to ONNX but seems the inference feature could not support it

TypeError: conv1d() received an invalid combination of arguments - got (NoneType, Parameter, Parameter, tuple, tuple, tuple, int), but expected one of:

(Tensor input, Tensor weight, Tensor bias, tuple of ints stride, tuple of ints padding, tuple of ints dilation, int groups)
didn't match because some of the arguments have invalid types: (!NoneType!, !Parameter!, !Parameter!, !tuple of (int,)!, !tuple of (int,)!, !tuple of (int,)!, int)
(Tensor input, Tensor weight, Tensor bias, tuple of ints stride, str padding, tuple of ints dilation, int groups)
didn't match because some of the arguments have invalid types: (!NoneType!, !Parameter!, !Parameter!, !tuple of (int,)!, !tuple of (int,)!, !tuple of (int,)!, int)

This is my code:

config = VitsConfig()
config.load_json("/content/drive/MyDrive/Technical/TTS/TTS API Files/elsie_config.json")
vits = Vits.init_from_config(config)
vits.load_checkpoint(config, "/content/drive/MyDrive/Technical/TTS/TTS API Files/checkpoint_1054000.pth")

vits.export_onnx()
vits.load_onnx("coqui_vits.onnx")

Please is there a solution to fixing the bug. Thank you

I tried converting multi speaker to ONNX and this what resulted:
TypeError: conv1d() received an invalid combination of arguments - got (NoneType, Parameter, Parameter, tuple, tuple, tuple, int), but expected one of: